# "IndexError: list index out of range" when reaching end of list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I pulled some data from a table on a web page, and put it into a list. However, when I reach the end of the list I get an "IndexError: list index out of range" error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://www.countyofdane.com/election/electiondetail.aspx?id=54").read())
table = soup.find("table", {"id":"gdvPrecinctDetail101"})

a = table.findAll("td")
slipstr = list(a)
data_list = []

for t in slipstr:
    t = str(t)
    new_t = t[4:-5]
    data_list.append(new_t)

x = 0
y = 9
for yes in data_list:
    if yes < len(data_list):
        break
    else:
        print data_list[x] + ": ",
        for data_point in data_list[x+1:y]:
            print data_point,
        print "\n"
        x += 9
        y += 9
```

Error Message:

```
print data_list[x] + ": ",
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you!

EDIT: There are 9 columns (candidates) of data in each row (city in Dane County), so thats why x and y increase by 9 for each trip through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the break condition of the loop into:

```
if x > len(data_list)-1:
    break
```

Comment: I still get the same error message, and interestingly enough I tried changing the last part after "len(data_list)" to "-10" and "-100" and it still produced the same error message. I think I did something wrong earlier in the code, but still not sure.

Comment: I ran the code with this adjustment and it does not give an index error anymore. It prints these lines: "T ALBION WDS 1-2:  369 732 1 11 0 0 0 3"  up to  "C VERONA WDS 6-9:  1248 2178 4 33 0 0 10 2". Did you change yes into x?

Comment: If your question has been solved by this answer you can set it to answered .

Answer (score 0):

Although the question about the index error is already answered, this problem woudn't even arise if you didn't flatten the table structure in the first place.

”Extracting” the text value of a cell by converting the  element into a HTML source fragment and then cut the  at the beginning and the  at the end is an ugly hack wich has some problems, like printing the „&“ in „C VERONA WDS 1 & 5“ as „&“.

Using the table structure and getting at the text content via the `text` attribute, the code may look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    url = 'https://www.countyofdane.com/election/electiondetail.aspx?id=54'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), 'lxml')
    rows = soup.find('table', id='gdvPrecinctDetail101').find('tbody')('tr')
    for row in rows:
        row_data = [td.text for td in row('td')]
        print(u'{0}: {1}'.format(row_data[0], ' '.join(row_data[1:])))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```